# API POST Endpoints and Image Processing

Tags: json, database, api, software-design

So, for my android app, not only do I get certain data that I would like to POST to an API endpoint via JSON format, but one of the data pieces is also an image. Everything besides the image goes into a postgresql database. I want to put the images somewhere (no important where) then put the link to that image in the database.

Here's the thing, while that image is connected to the other pieces of data I send to the API endpoint that gets put into the database, I would be sending the image somewhere else and then the link be put in at a different time. So here's my mental gymnastic I am trying to get over:

How would I send these two separate data pieces (an image and then all other data in a single JSON object) and have the image associated with that JSON object that get's put into the database without the image and data getting all mixed up due to multiple users doing the same thing?

To simplify, say I have the following information as a single JSON object going to an endpoint called `api.example.com/frontdoor`. The object looks something like this:

```
{
  "visitor_id": "5d548e53-c351-4016-9078-b0a572df0bca",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "appointment": false,
  "purpose": "blahblahblah..."
}
```

That JSON object is consumed by the server and is then put into their respective tables in the database.

At the same time, and image is taken and given a uuid as a file name and send to `api.example.com/face`, then the server processes it and somehow a adds link to the image in the proper database entry row.

The question is, how do I accomplish that? How would I go about relating these two pieces of data that get sent to two different places?

In the end, I plan on having a separate endpoint such as `api.example.com/visitors` provide a JSON object with a list of all visits that looks something like:

```
{
  "visits": [
               {
                 "visitor_id": "5d548e53-c351-4016-9078-b0a572df0bca",
                 "name": "John Doe",
                 "appointment": false,
                 "purpose": "blahblahblah..."
                 "image": "imgbin.example.com/faces/c3118272-9e9d-4c54-8824-8cf4cfaa679f.png"
               },
               ... 
            ]
}
```

Mainly, I am trying to get my head around the design of all of this so I can start writing code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, your question is about executing an action on the server side where two different sub services are involved - one service to update the text data in a sql db and another to store an image and then put the image's reference back to the main data. There are two approaches that come to my mind.

1) **Generate a unique id on the client side** and associate that to both json object upload an the image upload. And then when your image is uploaded, the image upload service can take this ID, find the corresponding record in SQL and update the image path. However generating client side unique IDs are not a recommended approach because there is a chance of collision such that more than 1 client generates the same ID which will break the logic. To work around this, before uploading, client can make a call to an **ID generation** service which will uniquely generate the ID on the server side and send it back to the client and then client can perform the upload step using the same approach. The downside to this approach is that the client needs to make an extra call to the server to get the unique ID. Advantage of this approach is that the UI can get separate updates for the data and the image as in when the data upload service is successful, it can say that the data is successfully updated and when the image is uploaded at some point in time later, then it can say that image upload is completed. Thus, the responses of each upload can be managed differently in this case. However if the data and image upload has to happen together and has to be atomic (the whole upload fails if either of data or image upload fails) then this approach can't be used because the server must group both these actions in a **transaction**.

2) Another approach is to **have a common endpoint for both image and data upload**. Both image and data get uploaded together in a single call to the server and the server first generates a unique ID and then makes two parallel calls to data upload service and image upload service and both these sub service calls get this unique ID as the parameter. If both uploads have to be atomic then the server must group these sub service calls in a transaction. Regarding returning response, it can be **synchronous or asynchronous**. If the UI needs to be kept waiting for the uploads to succeed, then the response will be synchronous and the server will have to wait for both these sub services to complete before returning a response. But if UI doesn't need to be kept waiting then the server can respond immediately after making calls to these sub services with a message that the upload request has been accepted. In this case, the sub services calls are processed asynchronously.

In my opinion, approach 2 is better because that way server has more control over grouping the related actions together. Regarding response, it depends on the use case. If the user cares about whether his post was properly recorded on the server (like making a payment) then it is better to have synchronous implementation. However if user initiates the action and leaves (as in the case of generating a report or sending an email) then it can have asynchronous implementation. Asynchronous implementation is better in terms of **server utilization** because server is free to accept other requests rather than waiting for the sub services' actions to complete.

These are 2 general approaches. I am sure there will be several variations or may be entirely different approaches for this problem.

Ah, too long of an answer, hope it helps. Let me know if further questions.